# Entity Framework 6 - Property name 'varchar' is already defined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'am using EF6 and code firt in project, but i get this error on creating the model

**Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'varchar' is already defined.**

below is my entity and my map

```
public class Menu
    {
        public Menu()
        {
            ListaFilhos = new List<Menu>();
        }
        public Int32 MenuID { get; set; }
        public String Nome { get; set; }
        public String Action { get; set; }
        public String Controller { get; set; }
        public String Url { get; set; }
        public Int32? Pai { get; set; }
        public Boolean? Ativo { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Menu> ListaFilhos { get; set; }
    }
```

Map

```
 public class MenuMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entidade.Menu>
    {
        public MenuMap()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.MenuID);
            Property(x => x.MenuID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(x => x.Pai).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Nome).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Url).HasColumnName("varchar").HasMaxLength(250);
            Property(x => x.Action).HasColumnName("varchar").HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(x => x.Controller).HasColumnName("varchar").HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(x => x.Ativo).IsRequired();
            ToTable("Menu");
        }
    }




 public class MenuGrupo
    {
        public MenuGrupo()
        {
            ListaMenu = new List<Menu>();
        }

        public Int32 MenuGrupoID { get; set; }
        public Int32 MenuID { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Menu> ListaMenu { get; set; }
    }


public class MenuGrupoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entidade.MenuGrupo>
    {
        public MenuGrupoMap()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.MenuGrupoID);
            Property(x => x.MenuGrupoID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(x => x.MenuID).IsRequired();
            ToTable("MenuGrupo");            
        }
    }
```

I guess my problem is on MenuMap, when i remove in the OnModelCreate, all orther map working.

What i'am doing wrong?

tks

Comment: Was `.HasColumnName("varchar")` suppose to be `.HasColumnType("varchar")`?

Comment: Tks, I dont see this. Its working.